# Conjugate exponential integral formula for Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, lie-groups

Somewhere in my notes the following formula appears

$\int_0^1 e^{s R} \frac{d R}{dt} e^{(1-s)R} ds = \frac{d}{dt} e^{R}$

where $R$ depends on $t$, and has values in a Lie algebra [$\mathfrak{so}(3)$ is what I was dealing with at the time].  If I assume this formula is true, I can make great simplifications in my work, so it's very important to me.  But I have two problems.

First, I can't remember where I got this.  I've looked carefully through my references, but can't find it anywhere.  Any good references for this formula?

Second, (though a good reference should cure this problem) I can't figure out why it's true.  When I use [the "Hadamard" Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_Hadamard_lemma), and expand both sides, I get vaguely similar-looking formulas, but can't quite get to equality.  Any ideas?

[On a related note, it seems like this use of integrals from 0 to 1 is pretty common in analysis of Lie groups/algebras.  Any good (but fairly basic) references that discuss this strategy per se, and its usefulness?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out.  I found a similar expression as Lemma 5.4 in Miller's ["Symmetry Groups and Their Applications"](http://www.ima.umn.edu/~miller/symmetrygroups.html).  The proof is easy, if you move one power of the exponent from the left side and apply the 'make things a function of $s$' trick to the *right* side.

Define
\begin{equation}
  B(s,t) = \left( \frac{d}{dt} e^{s R(t)} \right) e^{-s R(t)}
\end{equation}
Now we evaluate the derivative with respect to $s$:
\begin{aligned}
  \frac{\partial} {\partial s} B(s,t)
  &= \left[ \frac{d}{dt} \left( R(t) e^{s R(t)} \right) \right] e^{-s R(t)} - \left( \frac{d}{dt} e^{s R(t)} \right) e^{-s R(t)} R(t) \\
  &= \left[ \left( \frac{d}{dt} R(t) \right) e^{s R(t)} + R(t) \frac{d}{dt} \left( e^{s R(t)} \right) \right] e^{-s R(t)} - B(s,t) R(t) \\
  &= \dot{R}(t) + R(t) B(s,t) - B(s,t) R(t) \\
  &= \dot{R}(t) + \mathrm{ad}_{R(t)} B(s,t)
\end{aligned}
Here, $\dot{R}(t)$ is short-hand for the derivative by $t$, and $\mathrm{ad}_X Y$ is just defined as $X\,Y - Y\,X$.  Differentiating repeatedly, we see that
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\partial^j} {\partial s^j} B(s,t) = \mathrm{ad}_{R(t)}^{j-1} \dot{R}(t) + \mathrm{ad}_{R(t)}^j B(s,t)
\end{equation}

Since $B(s,t)$ is an entire function, we can expand it as a series in $s$.  The various coefficients are what we have just calculated, evaluated at $s=0$.  Then, the quantity we seek is just $B(1,t)$.
\begin{aligned}
  \left( \frac{d}{dt} e^{R(t)} \right) e^{-R(t)}
  &= B(1,t) \\
  &= \left. \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{s^j} {j!} \mathrm{ad}_{R(t)}^{j-1} \dot{R}(t) \right|_{s=1} \\
  &= \int_0^1 \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{s^j} {j!} \mathrm{ad}_{R(t)}^{j} \dot{R}(t)\, ds \\
  &= \int_0^1 e^{s R(t)}\, \frac{d R(t)}{dt}\, e^{-s R(t)}\, ds
\end{aligned}
That last equality comes from [the "Hadamard" lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_Hadamard_lemma) I mentioned above.  Multiplying each side of this equation on the right by $e^{R(t)}$ results in the formula as posed in my question.